# Coping dependencies before build and install a R library

Tags: r, rcpp

I am developing a R library with Rcpp.

This package has 2 external dependencies, I have it compiled and with the `*.so*` files in my path, following the structure:

```
my_R_package
    src
        include
            linux
                dependency1.so
                dependency1.so.0
                ...
                dependency2.so
                dependency2.so.0
                ...
        Makevars
```

In my `Makevars` file I have the `PKG_CPPFLAGS` and `PKG_LIBS` vars with the correct flags.

My problem is I can't use a -L./include/linux because ld does not understand the `.` path, and `-rpath` combined with `$ORIGIN` does not work because when R install the package generate the `.*so` in the R directory, and there can't find the dependencies.

So the only solution I see is to copy the files of my dependencies in a common path like `/usr/local/lib`. How can I do that? Can I use a `Makefile` instead the `Makevars`?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have dynamic libraries *inside your package* because

- CRAN would not let you upload object
- the dynamic linker `ldd` does not see these directories

So yes, I would suggest using *external packaging* of these libraries, and then have the R package depend on them.

Otherwise you could wrap these libraries if compiled *statically*.

Comment: Thanks! Compiled statically means without Rcpp?

Comment: It's all layered: your build scripts, via `configure` or from `src/Makevars` would need to build the library first, and then your usual Rcpp-using package build step would use them.  There are existing example, try eg package nloptr.